# SetInterval for falling movieclips

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I'm trying to make a game where apples fall but I cannot set intervals for every created movieclip. When I create it with the code below, move of the apple stops when another one is created.

```
function FallAnApple()
{
    _apple = "apple_" + _counter;
    attachMovie("apple", _apple, _counter);
    eval(_apple)._x = RandomX();
    eval(_apple)._y = -16;

    setInterval(function(){eval(_apple)._y += 2;}, 100);

    _counter += 1;
}
```

When I put an interval inside apple movieclip, I cannot access this._y inside the interval, but I can access this value inside the created movie itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep an array of your apples as you create them, and then change the coordinates of each apple in the array when the interval fires.

Comment: Make sure to call clearInterval when you're done. With only the one, you're less likely to create a memory leak, but better safe than sorry!

Answer (score 1):

the first line overwrites the contents of the _apple variable. so after that, both intervals are operating on the latest apple.